# Use sed or awk to remove lines not adjacent to pattern in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to delete any line that is not surrounding a ">" symbol.

Here is some sample data:

```
sample1.fasta
>R00003
ATCATACTACTACG
sample2.fasta
sample3.fasta
sample4.fasta
>R00003
ATACTACGTA
sample7.fasta
>R00003
ATGCATCAT
sample8.fasta
>R00003
AATCATCGACCT
sample9.fasta
sample10.fasta
>R00003
AGCATCTCAGTC
```

I tried using awk to help reveal the issue:

```
awk '{/fasta/?f++:f=0} f==2' R3.fasta
```

This returns:

```
sample3.fasta
sample10.fasta
```

This is diagnostic in that it shows where duplicates are present. However, I want to remove the lines that are not flanking the ">" symbol on either side. This does not remove them and only displays the second.

The result I expect is:

```
sample1.fasta
>R00003
ATCATACTACTACG
sample4.fasta
>R00003
ATACTACGTA
sample7.fasta
>R00003
ATGCATCAT
sample8.fasta
>R00003
AATCATCGACCT
sample10.fasta
>R0003
AGCATCTCAGTC
```

Where the lines not flaking the ">" symbol have been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the plain **`grep`** will suffice for this:

```
grep '^>' -C1 file | grep -v ^--$
```

First print one line above and one line below each line starting with `>` (use context `-C1`), then just filter out the `--` lines that `grep` inserts to separate each context.

---

But if you prefer **`awk`**:

```
awk '/^>/{print a ORS $0; getline; print} {a=$0}' file
```

Keep the previous line in `a`, and when a line starts with `>`, print the previous line (in `a`), the current line, and the next line (which we get with `getline`).

Answer (score 0):

From the example, it appears that you want all non-fasta lines and, for the fasta lines, you want only the last fasta file before the next `>`.  In that case, try:

```
$ awk 'f && !/fasta/{print f; f=""} /fasta/{f=$0; next} END{if(f)print f} 1' R3.fasta
sample1.fasta
>R00003
ATCATACTACTACG
sample4.fasta
>R00003
ATACTACGTA
sample7.fasta
>R00003
ATGCATCAT
sample8.fasta
>R00003
AATCATCGACCT
sample10.fasta
>R0003
AGCATCTCAGTC
```

#### How it works

1. `f && !/fasta/{print f; f=""}`

   If the variable `f` is set and the current line does not contain fasta, then print `f` and erase its current value.
2. `/fasta/{f=$0; next}`

   If the current line contains fasta, then save the current line to variable `f`, slip the rest of the commands, and jump to the `next` line.
3. `END{if(f)print f}`

   If `f` is still set to something after we have reached the end of the file, then print it.
4. `1`

   For all other lines, print them.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{if (/fasta/) f=$0; 
        else {if(f) print f; f=""; print}}' file
```

doesn't depend on number of lines in between.

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed ':A;/fasta$/!d;N;/\n>/!{s/.*\n//;bA};N' infile

sed '
:A              # label for jump
/fasta$/!d      # if the line end with fasta not delete
N               # add the next line in the pattern space
/\n>/!{         # if this new line don'\''t start with >
s/.*\n//        # delete it
bA}             # and jump to A
N               # else get the next line and print
' infile
```